# Nice-looking $x_i^j$

Tags: math-mode, superscripts

When I write `$x_i^j$`, the `j` is very high up, and it looks ugly.  (This problem is especially apparent in the `New Century Schoolbook` font.)

[image: $x_i^j$]

I know that TeX is capable of automatically lowering it, since for example, `$x_i^1$` looks fine.  Is there a clean way to fix this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fouriernc} % use the New Century Schoolbook font
\begin{document}
Contrast $x_i^j$ to $x_i^1$.  Why is the $j$ so high up?
\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "very high"? What I observe with the compiled code given is the default output of `TeX`. But if you want to raise or lower the j then that is something else.

Comment: If you use `\smash{j}` instead of `j` TeX will think it has zero height and (more importantly) zero depth and it will look more like the version with the `1`.

Comment: Have a look at the [`tensind`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tensind) package. It sets the high and low indices properly aligned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fouriernc} % use the New Century Schoolbook font
\begin{document}
Contrast $x_i^{\smash{j}}$ and $x_i^j$ to $x_i^i$.  Why is the $j$
so high up?
\end{document}
```